# Refraction/reflection stones three js

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

Есть модель(геометрия) камня. Можно ли добиться, у three js такого результата как [вот здесь](https://www.meisterschmuck.ch/shop/en/engagement-rings/Engagement-Ring-31-2-4-mm-0101-0000-0000-1-Brill-0-16-ct-G-VS-53-mm.html?2dview=1) в b4w к примеру, или приближенно?
Есть [примеры](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=refr#webgl_materials_cubemap_refraction) где показано преломление с помощью cubeTextureLoader, и так же [пример](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_reflectivity.html) где идет разделение модели на front и back. Но результат не такой как хотелось бы, та и разделять или клонировать модель не хотелось бы(
Я попробовал это сделать следующим образом без envMap

```
new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    //envMap: textureCube,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true
});
```

Результат близок, но он прозрачен и внутри нет никакого преломление( http://joxi.ru/D2PYVzxFpnqJJA

И с помощью cubeTexture

```
var path = "texture/", format = '.jpg';

var urls = [
    path + 'px' + format, path + 'nx' + format,
    path + 'py' + format, path + 'ny' + format,
    path + 'pz' + format, path + 'nz' + format
  ];

  var textureCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load(urls);
      textureCube.mapping = THREE.CubeRefractionMapping;

      new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
           color: 0xffffff,
           envMap: textureCube,
           side: THREE.DoubleSide,
           reflectivity: 1,
           refractionRatio: 0.99,
```

Но результат тоже не очень http://joxi.ru/1A5xQK3hnLDbQ2

Или какими то картами, специфическими? Любые идеи. Спасибо!

Comment: _"разделение модели на front и back"_. Увы и ах, это пока единственная доступная техника создания более-менее правдоподобно выглядящих драгкамней в Three.js. На shadertoy.com можно поискать примеры по ключевым словам "diamond" и "gem". Выглядят они [красиво](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ltfXDM), но вряд ли такая красота стоит того, чтобы fps проседал до величины меньше 10 в полноэкранном режиме :)

Comment: эх (
На shadertoy.com через поиск, браузер умирает у меня =)
Попадал на примеры этого сайта, честно говоря, даже и не пытался их как то использовать =)
Спасибо за отзыв @prisoner849!

Comment: Да было бы за что :)